# How to use Delphi Form inheritance with environment path

Tags: delphi, repository, delphi-10.3-rio

I have some forms I have created in a local directory D:\PsToolBox. I added them to the repository, now when I inherit from them the IDE adds the Base form to the project's file, no problem. I get :

```
PsListView in 'D:\PsToolbox\Source\View\PsListView.pas' {frmPsList},
Unit4 in 'Unit4.pas' {frmPsList4};
```

However I code on 2 different computers through version control on BitBucket. The PsToolBox directory is in  different locations so I need a common path in the project file.
I tried creating an environment variable PsToolBox with the path D:\ToolBox on the first machine and then editing the dpr file path of the base form to

```
PsListView in '${PsToolbox}\Source\View\PsListView.pas' {frmPsList},
```

This compiles and runs, however if I try to edit my form I get an error that the system cannot find the file. Also moving between projects in the group triggers the error as well. Closing and reopen same result.

I tried adding the environment path

```
$(PsToolbox)\Source\View
```

to both the Tools/Options/Langauge/Delphi/Library Windows32 platform, as well as the project search path. No Joy.

What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible, as the compiler does not support use of environmental variables in source code. As you're trying to use the same source on both machines with different configurations, I don't see a way to do it with conditional defines, either.

Comment: You don't need to add additional environment path for this. All you do is just add folder in which `PslistView.pas` file is located to global `Browsing Path` under Tools/Options/Language/Delphi/Library on each computer. And each computer would have this configured differently since you have mentioned file in different folders on different computers. Do not add this information into your project options since settings in Project Options could override Global ones.

Comment: SilverWariiorThis does not work

Comment: I tried that initially. When you inherit a Form or DataModule from the repository the IDE adds the Base unit to your project file with an absolute path. Moving to a different computer that uses a different path breaks this. read my post and note code example. My desktop has a D drive. The Base class is added with D drive path, my laptop does not have a D drive so no path settings will fix this

Comment: Ken, Thanks. I guess I'll just move the Base files into my project. Weird that the compiler has no problem but the IDE chokes. Like I said it compiles and runs fine it's just the IDE editing that doesn't work.